# Return all matches in excel

Tags: excel

guys!
I am developing a table to return the activities designated for each member of my company. The table with all the activities and members is:

Note: Members are positioned in column M (Starting at M2)
Activities are positioned in column H (Starting at H2)

[image: table]

Using that table as reference, i am developing individuals tables for each member of my company, and their respective activities. See the example below:

Note: Individual member are positioned at S2 cell;
I am trying to show his activities in column T (Starting at T2).

[image: table]

To accomplish that, i've try to use this formula:

`=IF(ROWS($1:1)>COUNTIF($M$2:$M$70;$S$2);"";INDEX($H$2:$H$70;SMALL(IF($M$2:$M$70=$S$2;ROWS($M$2:$M$70)-ROWS($M$2)+1;FALSE);ROWS($1:1))))`

This formula is working partially. The only problem is that it is not returning activities with more than one member designated.

To solve this, tried to substitute the following part of the formula:

`IF($M$2:$M$70=$S$2;`

To:

`IF($M$2:$M$70=ISTEXT($S$2);`

but it is not working. Could you help? Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

You need SEARCH (not case sensitive) or FIND (case sensitive) to locate one name in a group of names. I've also simplified your error control and retrieval limitation.

```
=IF(T1<>"", IFERROR(INDEX(H:H, AGGREGATE(15, 7, ROW($2:$70)/ISNUMBER(SEARCH(S$2, M$2:M$70)), ROW(1:1))), ""), "")
```

Comment: Sorry, i just know the basics of excel, i tried to use your formula but doenst work... but thanks for the help!